# display video from url

Tags: android, video

Can you give an example, how to display video from the url?

Comment: Just google it you will come across a lot of samples... Even API Demo samples that comes along with Android SDK has one.

Answer (score 1):

The easier way:

```
public class A extends Activity{
    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        super.onCreate(b);
        VideoView videoView = new VideoView(this);
        setContentView(videoView);

        videoView.setVideoPath("http://example.com/video.mp4");
        videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }
}
```